# How to hierarchically find available functions in the minibuffer with stock emacs

Tags: completion, minibuffer

I accidentally pressed some keys and found a feature that looked really useful. It gave me the option to hierarchically select a command/function to run in the minibuffer. There was some explanatory text at the top, saying I could use PageUp to go to the window to select completions. I hesitate to call it completions, because, while it was very similar to the window you get with `M-x ?`, it wasn't that (for one, that text about PageUp isn't there).

With the latter you get an alphabetical list of commands. With the feature I stumbled upon, there was some hierarchy to it. E.g. there was an option "file". When I selected that with  `f` I got more options, like `find-file`.

I immediately installed `command-log-mode`, but I haven't reached it again so far.

Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2020-08-21`

Comment: The command `view-lossage`, bound to `C-h l`, will be helpful if this sort of thing happens again: it shows you what  keys you pressed and what command they ran.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!

Comment: Since you say "stock Emacs", meaning I guess that you aren't talking about using any 3rd-party libraries, please specify your Emacs version: `M-x emacs-version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the emacs sources and grepped for the text I remembered. Apparently I just described the text interface to the menu bar, reached with `` M-` ``  by default. Case closed (and not as useful as it looked at first glance).